# SQL - transpose rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to achieve the following:

Given:

```
Name | Color   | Value |
------------------------
John |  Red    |   2   |
------------------------
John |  Blue   |   5   |
------------------------
John | Yellow  |   10  | 
------------------------
```

Expected:

```
Name |  Red  |  Blue  |  Yellow  |
----------------------------------
John |   2   |    5   |    10    |
----------------------------------
```

Essentially what I am hoping to do is make the color column individual colums with their value as the row value. There is a catch though, you can only use the following SQL functions:

**Aggregates**

Avg(), Count(), Max(), Min(), Sum(), Round()

**Arithmetic Operators**

- (add), - (subtract), / (divide), % (modulo), * (multiply)

**Comparison Operators**

= (equals), > (greater than), < (less than), >= (greater than or equal to), <= (less than or equal to), <> (not equal to), != (not equal to), !< (not less than), !> (not greater than)

**Logical Operators**

And, Or, Not, Between, In, Like, Any, All, Some, Exists

**Functions**

Case, Cast, Convert, Current_timestamp, DateAdd, DateDiff, DateName, DatePart, GetDate(), IsDate, Left, Len, Lower, Ltrim, Replace, Replicate, Reverse, Right, Rtrim, Space, Str, Substring, SUBSTRING ( expression, start , length), Sysdatetime, Upper

I have been able to get it to show the color as the column header and return its value. However this results in additional color values being returned too like so:

```
Name |   Red   |
----------------
John |    2    |
----------------
John |         |
----------------
John |         |
----------------
```

I know that the other color values are occupying the other rows because I added an additional column with the color name. The formula I used is as follows:

```
CASE Color WHEN 'Red' THEN Value END
```

I know I am missing a constraint but I don't know what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand, you're just missing the conditional aggregation and Group By

**Example**

```
Select Name
      ,Red   = sum(case when Color='Red'    then Value end)
      ,Blue  = sum(case when Color='Blue'   then Value end)
      ,Yellow= sum(case when Color='Yellow' then Value end)
 From  YourTable
 Group By Name
```

**Returns**

```
Name    Red  Blue   Yellow
John    2    5      10
```

Comment: Hey John thank you for the response. That answer won't work but I don't have access to the select and group by options. I just have access to the functions I provided in the original question

Comment: @NSaid . . . You specify that you can use `sum()`, so I don't see the issue with `group by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't have access to the Group by function. Just to the functions listed in the original question

Answer (score 1):

How about "correlated subqueries"?

```
SELECT ot.NAME, 
(SELECT SUM(t1.RED) FROM xTable as t1 where t1.NAME = ot.NAME) as RED,
(SELECT SUM(t1.BLUE) FROM xTable as t1 where t1.NAME = ot.NAME) as BLUE,
(SELECT SUM(t1.YELLOW) FROM xTable as t1 where t1.NAME = ot.NAME) as YELLOW
FROM xTable as ot
```

Answer (score 1):

Late update.  If 2012+, perhaps you can use the window function.

There is no `GROUP BY`, but there is an `DISTINCT`.

**Example**

```
Select Distinct
       Name
      ,Red   = sum(case when Color='Red'    then Value end) over (Partition By Name)
      ,Blue  = sum(case when Color='Blue'   then Value end) over (Partition By Name)
      ,Yellow= sum(case when Color='Yellow' then Value end) over (Partition By Name)
 From  @YourTable
```